# Why do I get an error when I create a list?

Tags: java, libgdx

guys! I am a novice developer in LibGDX and I have some problems presenting the list. I get the next mistake.

```
public class ChangeSongState extends State {

    ScrollPane scrollPane;
    List<String> list;
    Skin skin;
    TextureAtlas atlas;
    float gameWidth, gameHeight;
    private Stage stage;

    public ChangeSongState(GameStateManager game) {
        super(game);
        atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.atlas"));
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("SimpleSkin.json"), atlas);
    }


    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(dt);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        list = new List<>(skin);
        String[] strings = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};
        list.setItems(strings);
        stage.addActor(list);
    }
}
```

String containing error:

```
list = new List<>(skin);
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List.layout(List.java:179)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Widget.validate(Widget.java:88)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List.getPrefWidth(List.java:390)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List.<init>(List.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List.<init>(List.java:60)
    at com.stroenev.game.states.ChangeSongState.render(ChangeSongState.java:45)
    at com.stroenev.game.states.GameStateManager.render(GameStateManager.java:51)
    at com.stroenev.game.PianoTilesMain.render(PianoTilesMain.java:36)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:232)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
```

I also attach a Json file.

```
{
    "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
      "black": { "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
      "white": { "r": 1, "g": 1, "b": 1, "a": 1 }
    },

  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
      "default-font": { "file": "font.fnt" }
    },

  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
    "default": {
        "font": "default-font",
        "fontColor": "black"
      }
    },
  

  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle": {
    "default": {
      "font": "default-font"
    }
  }
}
```

Atlas and skin objects are not empty. But for some reason the list is not created and I can not understand what the matter is, I did not find any good video lessons, please tell me what the problem may be.

Comment: You try try to simply instantiate a list which is impossible because it's an interface.
Try `... = new ArrayList<>();`
Also note that theres no default constructor so you can't immeaditaly add an item to the list (which btw, in your example wouldn't work because you try to add a `Skin` to `List<String>`

Comment: My bad. I just looked at the
"String containing error"
and assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to one of the response authors, the error was as follows:

```
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle": {
    "default": {
      "font": "default-font",
      "selection": "default-select-selection"
    }
  }
```